# Issue Regarding SWRevealViewController Displaying Table Contents

Tags: xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

Firstly, I'd like to state that in the simulator my "app" is working flawlessly, the problem arises as soon as I compile and run the "app" on my phone.

The bar button item doesn't work nor do any pan gestures.

However, in the simulator, as stated, no issues.

However, when running the app on my phone I get this error:

```
App[2639:187670] [1;31m[OTRLocation] [m[0;31m../Tweak/Tweak.xm:121[m [0;30;41mERROR:[m logos: nil class SpringBoard
```

CoreFoundation = 1240.100000

I've changed the segues, ensured there are no problems with the code and so forth. However, to no avail. I just can't seem to understand as to why, when ran on a device, I get this issue.

If anyone could shed some light on the matter, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

UPDATE: Just ran the app on another iPhone. Good news no error appears in the console however, sad news is that this problem still continues to persist.

Comment: can you add any useful information to help you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this issue has been address. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have your iPhone jailbroken and `Anywhere!` tweak installed. It causes this warning. Uninstall the tweak and Xcode won't argue anymore.